# Getting errors in sendkeys command in appium (v.1.2.0) under selendroid mode (Real Device < 17 )

Tags: appium, selendroid

I just updated Appium 1.1.0 to 1.2.0, With previous version automation worked fine. But surprisingly when i update Appium i got below errors in sendkeys.

Appium Logs:

```
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/892ef5c3-267a-f50d-e28b-9b26a9ccd785/element 200 70.640 ms - 122
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/892ef5c3-267a-f50d-e28b-9b26a9ccd785/element/d764396c-6598-5920-d8c1-85ee7c2f44e5/value {"id":"d764396c-6598-5920-d8c1-85ee7c2f44e5","value":["abc"]}
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/892ef5c3-267a-f50d-e28b-9b26a9ccd785/element/d764396c-6598-5920-d8c1-85ee7c2f44e5/value
debug: Request received with params: {"id":"d764396c-6598-5920-d8c1-85ee7c2f44e5","value":["abc"]}
debug: Setting text on element 'd764396c-6598-5920-d8c1-85ee7c2f44e5': 'abc'
debug: Making http request with opts: {"url":"http://localhost:8080/wd/hub/session/892ef5c3-267a-f50d-e28b-9b26a9ccd785/element/d764396c-6598-5920-d8c1-85ee7c2f44e5/value","method":"POST","json":{"value":["abc"]}}
**debug: Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED)","code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","origValue":"connect ECONNREFUSED"},"sessionId":"892ef5c3-267a-f50d-e28b-9b26a9ccd785"}**
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/892ef5c3-267a-f50d-e28b-9b26a9ccd785/element/d764396c-6598-5920-d8c1-85ee7c2f44e5/value 500 7.627 ms - 293
info: --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/892ef5c3-267a-f50d-e28b-9b26a9ccd785 {}


Driver info: test.utils.SwipeableWebDriver
Capabilities [{automationName=selendroid, platformVersion=16, platform=ANDROID, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=android, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=selendroid, networkConnectionEnabled=true, rotatable=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=0.10.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:89)
    at test.screens.SignUpPage.fillPassword(SignUpPage.java:37)
    at test.utils.Functions.UserLogin(Functions.java:98)
    at test.LaunchTest.testLogin(EnigmaLaunchTest.java:121)
```

Thanks,

Priyank Shah

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error message and the problem was solved by changing the none default Selendroid port number to the default 8080. Try that and see what happens...